# Server side reactive Meteor publication

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

Assume the following current case:

- I do have a collection "Tables"
- A table is an object with properties like {private:0, private1,private2,…} (seats 0,1,2…)
- I publish the collection with 2 arguments, one the tableId the second one the seat.
- Given the seat, the publication will filter (hide) properties the client must not be able to see.
- For now the tableID and seat were taken from the client's session so everything was reactive.
- I have a "takeSeat(seatNb)" method. If a client invoke this method and is allowed to seat at the table, the seat number is sent back to client which then put it into it's session under the seat key. This will therefore update the subscription and filter the table's seats content correctly.

I'm not satisfied by this design because I realised that the client might be cheating by subscribing to a seat by itself. Also (and more important) I'm using another DDP client in c++ and would like to keep this logic part in the server side. i.e. not to have to subscribe with another seat once I get one, if I do take a seat at a table I would like the server to show the right fields on the table by itself.

After several searches I decided to add a collection aside for "Players" so that I might easily get notified within my "tables" collection a "player" is added or removed to a table. But this is only half of the problem. I do have to actually change the handler of the publication itself so that the filter will become reactive. This is where I'm stuck, here is some simplified code to understand the case:

```
Meteor.publish("current-table", function(table_id)
        {
            var self = this;

            var handle = Players.find({"tableID": table_id}).observeChanges(
                    {
                        added: function(id)
                        {
                            console.log("A player joined the table added");
                            self.changed("tables", table_id);
                        },
                        removed: function(id) {
                            console.log("A player left the table");
                            self.changed("tables", table_id);
                        }
                    });

            self.onStop(function() {
                handle.stop();
            });

            // PUBLISH THE TABLE BUT HIDE SOME FIELDS BEFORE
                var player = Players.findOne({"userID": this.userId, "tableID": table_id}) || {"seat": -1};
                var seat = player.seat;

                var privateFilter = {"private0": false, "private1": false, "private2": false, "private3": false};
                delete privateFilter["private" + seat];
                return Tables.find(table_id, {fields: privateFilter});
        });
```

How to proceed ? Is there a more elegant way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jrullmann's answer I decided to make a custom filtered publication using the reactivity of 2 collections. Here is my final code:

```
Meteor.publish("current-table", function(table_id)
        {
            var self = this;

            function getFilteredTable()
            {
                var player = Players.findOne({"userID": self.userId, "tableID": table_id}) || {"seat": -1};
                var seat = player.seat;
                var privateFilter = {"prv": false, "prv0": false, "prv1": false, "prv2": false, "prv3": false};
                delete privateFilter["prv" + seat];
                return Tables.findOne(table_id, {fields: privateFilter});
            }

            var tableHandler = Tables.find(table_id).observeChanges(
                    {
                        added: function()
                        {
                            self.added('tables', table_id, getFilteredTable());
                        },
                        removed: function()
                        {
                            self.removed('tables', table_id);
                        },
                        changed: function()
                        {
                            self.changed('tables', table_id, getFilteredTable());
                        }
                    });
            self.ready();
            self.onStop(function() {
                tableHandler.stop();
            });

            var handle = Players.find({"tableID": table_id}).observeChanges(
                    {
                        added: function(collection, id, fields)
                        {
                            self.changed('tables', table_id, getFilteredTable());
                            console.log("added");
                        },
                        removed: function(collection, id, fields)
                        {
                            // Little trick to avoid meteor use the former deleted (hidden) properties
                            self.removed('tables', table_id);
                            self.added('tables', table_id, getFilteredTable());
                            console.log("removed");
                        }
                    });

            self.onStop(function() {
                handle.stop();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this SO, I think my problem is similar to yours but am not sure how to bring them together? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34479708/271873

Answer (score 2):

You could store the seat in the user's profile.  Then your publication would watch for changes to the user's profile and adjust as appropriate.

For example:

```
Meteor.publish("current-table", function() {
  var self = this;
  var getFilteredTableForSeat = function(seat_id) {
    // Get the table for the given seat_id, filtering the fields as appropriate
  };

  var handle = Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}).observeChanges({
    changed: function (id, fields) {
      if(fields.profile)
        self.changed("tables", 'current-table', getFilteredTableForSeat(fields.profile.seat_id));
    }
  });

  self.added("tables", 'current-table', getFilteredTableForSeat(Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).profile.seat_id));
  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function() {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

If the user's seat changes then the current-table document of the Tables collection will update.

This example makes some assumptions, and will require adjustment if these aren't true for you:

- You can find a table given a seat_id (if you can't, you may need to store the table id in the user's profile as well)
- A seat_id always belongs to the same table (if it doesn't, you'll need to add a changed handler to wherever that information is stored)
- The table information returned by the publication doesn't change (if it does, you'll need to add a changed handle to the Table collection, similar to the user handle)

Comment: Perfect, I got your concept to adapt to my case. I actually have been able to do something even more trivial, many thanks for the clue

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and wrote these two atmosphere packages which solve the problem:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/server-deps

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/reactive-publish

Install the second package with meteorite, use "Meteor.reactivePublish" instead of "Meteor.publish" and it will automatically update when the results of any queries with the option {"reactive": true} change.

This example from the readme will publish precisely those items which the user's team can see, and will update when either the user changes team or the team's visible items change.

```
Meteor.reactivePublish(null, function() {
  if (this.userId) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}, {reactive: true});
    if (user.team) {
      var team = Collections.teams.findOne({_id: user.team}, {reactive: true});
      var visibleItems = _.compact(team.visibleItems);
      return Collections.items.find({_id: {$in: visibleItems}});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Both packages have no documentation and when I tried adding them the server started complaining about the onStop method missing.