# Meteor: Hide parts of a returned document

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to build a simple multiplayer card game in Meteor and I have two players with some cards. Now, when I subscribe to the Games collection where the Game document has the players and their cards, all the browser clients get **all the data**, and that's bad.

I can easily create a client side filter to display only those cards for that one user and hide the other cards, but **the data** is already at the browser client and anyone who knew what they were doing can just see that data. It would not be that hard to write a little client-side script to show it all the time in the page.

I actually found it in just under a minute in the console, it is under this.Games._collection._docs._map[""], and you can see all the cards for both players...

I saw in the tutorial Todo App that we can filter *the rows* to be returned, which is fine. But, I am wondering if it is possible to filter parts of the Documents returned?

So, my question is: **Is there a way to only publish the masked data to the clients?**

What I mean is, for example, the collection Game is something like this:

```
game: {
  player1: {
    username: "john",
    cards: "S8 HA D9 CQ C8"
  }
  player2: {
    username: "mike",
    cards: "HQ D7 SK H8 S7"
  }
}
```

The client for "john" **should** get it like this:

```
game: {
  player1: {
    username: "john",
    cards: "S8 HA D9 CQ C8"
  }
  player2: {
    username: "mike",
    cards: "XX XX XX XX XX"
  }
}
```

While the client for "mike" **should** get it like this:

```
game: {
  player1: {
    username: "john",
    cards: "XX XX XX XX XX"
  }
  player2: {
    username: "mike",
    cards: "HQ D7 SK H8 S7"
  }
}
```

Would something like this even be possible *and still be reactive*?

Or do I need to split my players into different collections and then filter those documents returned by username/access?

But even so I still would need to mask the cards because I still need to show *how many cards* the "other" player has in his hands without showing which ones they are..

I am guessing that if possible, this should be something in

```
Meteor.publish("games", function () {
    return Games.find({});
});
```

But I cannot figure out what to add there to make it work as described...

---

**EDIT:** I think [this section of the Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) may help me here. I will try to make several publishes of the Games collection, one that publishes only data that everyone is allowed to see, like the count of cards each player has, and another publish which shows the cards only if the user is allowed to see them.

---

**EDIT 2:** Hm. From [the Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) I see this:

```
// server: publish the rooms collection, minus secret info.
Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {
  return Rooms.find({}, {fields: {secretInfo: 0}});
});

// ... and publish secret info for rooms where the logged-in user
// is an admin. If the client subscribes to both streams, the records
// are merged together into the same documents in the Rooms collection.
Meteor.publish("adminSecretInfo", function () {
  return Rooms.find({admin: this.userId}, {fields: {secretInfo: 1}});
});
```

So, I tried to do the same like this:

```
Meteor.publish("games", function () {
    return Games.find({}, {
        fields: {
            "player1.cards": 0,
            "player2.cards": 0
        }
    });
});

Meteor.publish("playerCards1", function () {
    return Games.find({ "player1.userId": this.userId }, {
        fields: {
            "player1.cards": 1
        }
    });
});

Meteor.publish("playerCards2", function () {
    return Games.find({ "player2.userId": this.userId }, {
        fields: {
            "player2.cards": 1
        }
    });
});
```

With, of course, on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("games");
Meteor.subscribe("playerCards1");
Meteor.subscribe("playerCards2");
Games = new Mongo.Collection("games");
```

But cards are now not passed at all. It's as if the `playerCards1` and `playerCards1` publishes do not work...

Comment: try to `console.log` to debug on the publication. You might be surprised ;)

Comment: well, it shows the userId and then undefined for the Game document since the publish happens before the Game is created... but when I restart one client to fire it again it shows the Game document properly based on the search criteria... So, I am surprised that the query is fine but just not reaching the client :(

Comment: based on your previous question about publication, i assume you put the `subscribe` code in the collection file. That is not a good habit. Can you put it in the `router` or in the `Template.<your-template-name>.rendered` ?

Comment: Wait, is the publish/subscribe happening only once? Meaning that if the user is not in player1 when the client subscribes then it will never get the data? :( CRAP!

Comment: I added the subscribe into the template which renders the cards, and now the publish method console.log prints the correct result but the client still does not show it :(

Comment: open chrome console or whatever console to debug. You can type `Games.find()` to see whatever is pushed to the client

Comment: I'm using Games._collection._docs._map already and even after the subscribe hits the server the cards data is still missing from it :(

Comment: sorry mate. i think you are closed to it, just spend sometime to debug cos if it hit the publication and the query in the publication can return something, client will definitely see that part. That is where `meteor` is shinning. I need to sleep now. It is late here already. will check it out tomorrow if you still have error

Comment: thanks, have a good night...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using the [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) package:

```
Meteor.publish("games", function () {
    this.autorun(function (c) {
        var game = Games.findOne({
            $or: [
                { "player1.userId": this.userId },
                { "player2.userId": this.userId }
            ]
        });
        if (game) {
            if (this.userId === game.player1.userId) {
                return Games.find({}, { fields: { "player2.cards": 0 } });
            }
            if (this.userId === game.player1.userId) {
                return Games.find({}, { fields: { "player1.cards": 0 } });
            }
            return Games.find({  // this will return only one game
                $or: [
                    { "player1.userId": this.userId },
                    { "player2.userId": this.userId }
                ]
            }, {
                    fields: {
                        "player1.cards": 0,
                        "player2.cards": 0
                    }
                });
        }
        return Games.find({}, {  // this will all games
            fields: {
                "player1.cards": 0,
                "player2.cards": 0
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Today I realized that my first solution is not good if you have multiple games in progress which is the standard scenario, because then the user sitting in player1 in one game will get the cards of all player1 players in all the games. So, I updated the answer to a proper solution that handles that problem as well.